# Web Scraping VBA is getting slower and slower need any solution

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I am facing unknown problem.. here is my VBA code.. code is working perfectly as I want.. the problem is every next day VBA code is getting slower.  in a first day it was too much faster extracting data from URL.. approx I run this code for  60000 urls.. now its getting slower almost 1/3 speed down grad. please if any help could be possible

```
        Public Sub GetTelNumber()

        On Error Resume Next

        Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument
        Dim url As String
        Dim N As Long
        Dim XY As Long
        Dim re As Object
        Dim Str, SG As String



        For Rept = 1 To 1000
        Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        XY = 50
        G = ActiveCell.Row
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then End





        For N = ActiveCell.Row To ActiveCell.Row + XY


                url = Sheets("ExtData").Range("A" & N).Value
                With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
                    .Open "GET", url, False
                    .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
                    .Send
                    sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
                    S = .responseText
                End With

                Dim cipherKey As String, cipherDict As Object
                Set cipherDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                cipherKey = Split(Split(sResponse, "smoothing:grayscale}.icon-")(1), ".mobilesv")(0)
                cipherKey = Replace$(cipherKey, ":before{content:""\9d", Chr$(32))

                Dim arr() As String, tempArr() As String, i As Long, j As Long
                arr = Split(cipherKey, """}.icon-")
                For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                    tempArr = Split(arr(i), Chr$(32))
                    cipherDict(tempArr(0)) = i 'needs adjustment
                Next

                Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
                Set html = New HTMLDocument
                Dim storesTextToDecipher As Object

                With html
                    .body.innerHTML = sResponse

                        Set storesTextToDecipher = .querySelectorAll(".telnowpr")

                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = UCase(Mid(html.querySelector(".e_prop").href, InStrRev(html.querySelector(".e_prop").href, "-") + 1, 100))
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = html.querySelector(".fn").innerText
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = Split(html.querySelectorAll("#brd_cm_srch")(0).innerText, " in")(0)

                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = html.querySelectorAll(".lng_add")(2).innerText
                        If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = "" Then
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = html.querySelectorAll(".lng_add")(1).innerText
                        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = "" Then
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = html.querySelectorAll(".lng_add")(0).innerText
                        End If

                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6) = WorksheetFunction.Proper(Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, S, "addressRegion"":(.*"")"), Chr$(34), vbNullString)))
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, S, "postalCode"":(.*"")"), Chr$(34), vbNullString))

                        SG = Split(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7))(0)
                        SG = Mid(SG, 1, InStrRev(SG, ",") - 1)
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5) = Trim(Mid(SG, InStrRev(SG, ",") + 1, 100))


                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7), Sheets("India PinCode").Columns("A:F"), 3, 0)
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7), Sheets("India PinCode").Columns("A:F"), 4, 0)
                        'ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10) = GetWANO(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)) 'if wa no need together
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10) = GetWALink(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1))
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11) = Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, S, "url"":(.*)BZDET"), Chr$(34), vbNullString)) & "BZDET"
                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13) = GetStoreNumber(storesTextToDecipher.Item(1), cipherDict)

                        If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13) = "" Then
                           ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13) = "No"
                        ElseIf StringCount(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13), "X") * 14 <> Len(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13)) Then
                           ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13) = "Missing:"
                        End If

                        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14) = html.querySelectorAll(".whatsapptxt")(0).innerText


                Range("A" & N + 1).Select
                Range("P1") = N - G
                End With



        Next N

                Dim LastRow As Long
                Dim sht As Worksheet

                Set sht = Sheets("FDATA")
                LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                Range("A2:O" & XY + 2).Copy
                sht.Range("A" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                    :=False, Transpose:=False
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Range("A2:O" & XY + 2).Delete Shift:=xlUp



                Range("A2").Select
                ActiveWorkbook.Save



        Next Rept
    End Sub
```

Update Code as per suggetion

```
    Public Sub GetTelNumber()
On Error Resume Next

    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Dim N As Long
    Dim re, Cr, cipherDict As Object
    Dim sResponse, cipherKey, Str, SG As String
    Dim myArr, RsltArr(14) As Variant

    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    Set Cr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set cipherDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument

  For Rept = 1 To 50

    myArr = Application.Transpose(Range("A2:A52"))

    Call Clear_Browser
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

    'Call UpdateStop

    For N = 1 To 50

            With Cr
                .Open "GET", myArr(N), False
                .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
                .Send
                sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
                S = .responseText
            End With

            cipherKey = Split(Split(sResponse, "smoothing:grayscale}.icon-")(1), ".mobilesv")(0)
            cipherKey = Replace$(cipherKey, ":before{content:""\9d", Chr$(32))

            Dim arr() As String, tempArr() As String, i As Long, j As Long
            arr = Split(cipherKey, """}.icon-")

            For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                tempArr = Split(arr(i), Chr$(32))
                cipherDict(tempArr(0)) = i 'needs adjustment
            Next

            Dim storesTextToDecipher As Object

            With html
                .body.innerHTML = sResponse
                    Set storesTextToDecipher = .querySelectorAll(".telnowpr")

                    RsltArr(0) = UCase(Mid(html.querySelector(".e_prop").href, InStrRev(html.querySelector(".e_prop").href, "-") + 1, 100))
                    RsltArr(1) = html.querySelector(".fn").innerText
                    RsltArr(2) = Split(html.querySelectorAll("#brd_cm_srch")(0).innerText, " in")(0)

                    RsltArr(3) = html.querySelectorAll(".lng_add")(2).innerText

                    If RsltArr(3) = vbNullString Then
                    RsltArr(3) = html.querySelectorAll(".lng_add")(1).innerText
                    ElseIf RsltArr(3) = vbNullString Then
                    RsltArr(3) = html.querySelectorAll(".lng_add")(0).innerText
                    End If

                    RsltArr(5) = WorksheetFunction.Proper(Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, S, "addressRegion"":(.*"")"), Chr$(34), vbNullString)))
                    RsltArr(6) = Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, S, "postalCode"":(.*"")"), Chr$(34), vbNullString))

                    SG = Split(RsltArr(3), RsltArr(6))(0)
                    SG = Mid(SG, 1, InStrRev(SG, ",") - 1)
                    RsltArr(4) = Trim(Mid(SG, InStrRev(SG, ",") + 1, 100))
                    RsltArr(7) = Application.VLookup(Val(RsltArr(6)), Sheets("India PinCode").Columns("A:F"), 3, 0)
                    RsltArr(8) = Application.VLookup(Val(RsltArr(6)), Sheets("India PinCode").Columns("A:F"), 4, 0)
                    'ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10) = GetWANO(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)) 'if wa no need together
                    RsltArr(9) = GetWALink(myArr(N), RsltArr(0))
                    RsltArr(10) = Trim$(Replace$(GetString(re, S, "url"":(.*)BZDET"), Chr$(34), vbNullString)) & "BZDET"
                    RsltArr(12) = GetStoreNumber(storesTextToDecipher.Item(1), cipherDict)


                    RsltArr(13) = html.querySelectorAll(".whatsapptxt")(0).innerText
            End With

            Range("B" & N + 1 & ":O" & N + 1) = RsltArr

            Erase RsltArr

    Next N
            'Call UpdateStart
            Dim LastRow As Long
            Dim sht As Worksheet

            Set sht = Sheets("FDATA")
            LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            Range("A2:O52").Copy
            sht.Range("A" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Range("A2:O52").Delete Shift:=xlUp
            ActiveWorkbook.Save

            Erase myArr

    Next Rept
End Sub
```

Comment: For one, there's no need to create 1000 `vbscript.regexp` objects. Move the instantiation `Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")` outside the loop and do the same for `MSXML2.XMLHTTP`. Store it in an object variable and call it in the loop.

Comment: how can I set outside MSXML2.XMLHTTO as every time I used new URL.. please can you modified my code. as I am not much familier with VBA

Comment: By setting all this `CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")`,`CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`,`CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")` before the `for loop` as @Kostas K. has already mentioned.

Comment: Have urls in an array and loop that array; write results first to an array. At the end, write array to sheet. Also, issue requests in batches with a small pause every n requests so as to be a nice netizen.

Comment: Sir here I edit my old Code to change url Arry and results Arry also modify instantiation outside to the loop. as per suggestion  thanks to all for guided now these code is working perfect.  even I wish if you can look my update code and suggest me some more things..